# How to push changes to BitBucket Remote repository - remote address textbox is missing

Tags: .net, git, version-control, visual-studio-2013

I was unable to setup a remote bitbucket repository for my .NET webform projet.

I am using Microsoft Git Provider as my source control plug-in within Visual Studio 2013. I've added source control to my project and submit an initial commit. In the Ynsynced Commits section the Sync button is grayed out. I also don't have any place to enter the remote repository URL (using BitBucket).

How can I configure the remote repository URL so I can push changes to the BitBucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directly the GIT BASH. Go into your directory `cd ...` and put `git remote add name_of_your_choice adress_of_bitbucket.git`

You can find adress of your git repo when you click on "clone".

Afterwards, you'll be able to do a git push.

**EDIT:**
Ok, when you've clicked on `Unsynced Commits`, below you'll see `Publish to Remote Repository` and again below `Enter the url of an empty Git repo.`

You can try the command above (git remote etc...), there is only one way to add a remote repository to git so yes, I'm sure at 99%. Visual studio should detect the remote repo.

Comment: hi, are you sure the command is right, it shows me the "usage:" info

Comment: That's my problem, I don't see the "Publish to Remote Repository". I saw it only once, and I entered the wrong address, now I don't can't see it, it's missing from the Unsynced commits section. I also didn't find any place to modify it. Maybe re-doing everything from scratch will show it, but I don't know how to restart the all process.

Comment: Ok, with visual studio, I don't know. But, open the GIT BASH and go into the folder project (where .git folder is) and write `git remote -v`. You'll see every remote repositories. Tell me if it's empty or not.

Comment: There must be a way to modify the remote repository some place. BTW: the command needs an attribute tag (e.g. --mirror, --fetch, etc.)

Comment: We are getting somewhere. When I write the git remote -v, I see the wrong remote address that I've written. Tried: git remote add --mirror [the_repository_url] but the comment is wrong

Comment: Ok, Close visual studio and write `git remote rm name_of_remote_repo` to remove the wrong adress. The name of the remote repo is often `origin`. There is no other attribute (neither --mirror  nor --fetch)

Comment: Great, I removed the origin repo, now I get the option to enter the remote repository. Trying everything again..

Comment: Ok, you can open Visual Studio and try again to add remote repo with it.

Comment: I put the URL in the "publish to remote repository" and clicked the publish button, but I get a forever "publishing branch" loader, and it's never finishes. Should I get a user/password, because my repo is private?

Comment: Yes, if it's a private repo, with Bitbucket, you just need the password.

Comment: I think it'll be more difficult. I don't know if VS is able to use private repo https with password. Perhaps, you will have to use SSH key ...